# What's different between pointer with array in c?

Tags: c, pointers

I try to google this topic, but no one can explain clear. I try the below code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char * argv[]){

    char * p1 = "dddddd";
    const char * p2 = "dddddd";
    char p3[] = "dddddd";
    char * p4 =(char*)malloc(sizeof("dddddd")+1);
    strcpy(p4, "dddddd");
    //*(p1+2) = 'b'; // test_1
    //Output >>  Bus error: 10

    // *(p2+2) = 'b'; // test_2
    // Output >> char_point.c:11:13: error: read-only variable is not assignable
    *(p3+2) = 'b'; // test_3
    // Output >>
    //d
    //dddddd
    //dddddd
    //ddbddd

    *(p4+2) = 'k'; // test_4
    // Output >>
    //d
    //dddddd
    //dddddd
    //ddbddd
    //ddkddd

    printf("%c\n", *(p1+2));
    printf("%s\n", p1);
    printf("%s\n", p2);
    printf("%s\n", p3);
    printf("%s\n", p4);

    return 0;
}
```

I have try 3 tests, but only the `test_3` and `test_4` can pass. I know `const char *p2` is read only, because it's a constant value! but i don't know why `p1` can't be modified! which section of memory it's layout? BTW, I compile it on my Mac with `GCC`.

I try to compile it to dis-asm it by `gcc -S`, I got this.

```
.section    __TEXT,__text,regular,pure_instructions
.macosx_version_min 10, 13
.globl  _main
.p2align    4, 0x90
_main:                                  ## @main
    .cfi_startproc
## BB#0:
    pushq   %rbp
Lcfi0:
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
Lcfi1:
    .cfi_offset %rbp, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
Lcfi2:
    .cfi_def_cfa_register %rbp
    subq    $48, %rsp
    movl    $8, %eax
    movl    %eax, %ecx
    leaq    L_.str(%rip), %rdx
    movl    $0, -4(%rbp)
    movl    %edi, -8(%rbp)
    movq    %rsi, -16(%rbp)
    movq    %rdx, -24(%rbp)
    movq    %rdx, -32(%rbp)
    movl    L_main.p3(%rip), %eax
    movl    %eax, -39(%rbp)
    movw    L_main.p3+4(%rip), %r8w
    movw    %r8w, -35(%rbp)
    movb    L_main.p3+6(%rip), %r9b
    movb    %r9b, -33(%rbp)
    movq    %rcx, %rdi
    callq   _malloc
    xorl    %r10d, %r10d
    movq    %rax, -48(%rbp)
    movl    %r10d, %eax
    addq    $48, %rsp
    popq    %rbp
    retq
    .cfi_endproc

    .section    __TEXT,__cstring,cstring_literals
L_.str:                                 ## @.str
    .asciz  "dddddd"

L_main.p3:                              ## @main.p3
    .asciz  "dddddd"


.subsections_via_symbols
```

I want to know every pointer what i declaration, which section is it?

Comment: Not to put too fine a point on it, it is undefined behavior to modify a string literal in C.

Comment: But why the other `test_3` and `test_4` can be modify?

Comment: `p3[]` is an array of `char`, which you _can_ modify (here, `char p3[] = "dddddd";` _initializes_ `p3` with the contents of the string literal, but `p3` itself is not a string literal). `p4` points to a dynamic allocation of `char`, which you can also modify. Note that on some old systems string literals _could_ be modified, but the C Standard specifies that this is undefined behavior.

Comment: `sizeof("dddddd")` is basically the same as `sizeof(char*)`, not `strlen("dddddd")`

Comment: `p1` is pointing to read-only memory, even if you didn't use `const`. All string literals are read-only.

Comment: But this answer no clearly why and which section the memory layout . @Pablo

Comment: @FrankAK what? I don't understand you

Comment: @Pablo I have update my question with some asm code, which output from `gcc -S`, i want to know the layout of each pointer at the memory ! like my asm code show.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So

```
char * p1 = "dddddd";
```

this should be

```
const char * p1 = "dddddd";
```

String literals (the ones in quotes) reside in read-only memory. Even if you
don't use the `const` keyword in the declaration of the variable, `p1` still
points to read-only memory. So

```
*(p1+2) = 'b'; // test_1
```

is going to fail.

Here

```
*(p2+2) = 'b'; // test_2
// Output >> char_point.c:11:13: error: read-only variable is not assignable
```

the compiler tells you, you cannot do that because you declared `p2` as `const`.
The difference between the first test and this one, is that the code *tries* to
modify a character and fails.

Now this:

```
char * p4 =(char*)malloc(sizeof("dddddd")+1);
```

First, do not cast `malloc` & friends. Second: the `sizeof`-operator returns the
number of bytes needed to store the expression in memory. `"ddddd"` is a string
literal, it returns a pointer to `char`, so `sizeof("dddddd")` returns the number
of bytes that a pointer to `char` needs to be stored in memory.

The correct function would be `strlen`:

```
char * p4 = malloc(strlen("dddddd")+1);
```

Note that in this case

```
char txt[] = "Hello world";
printf("%lu\n", sizeof(txt));
```

will print 12 and not 11. C strings are `'\0'`-terminated, that means that `txt`
holds all these characters **plus** the `'\0'`-terminating byte. In this case
`sizeof` doesn't return the number of bytes for a pointer, because `txt` is an
array.

```
void foo(char *txt)
{
    printf("%lu\n", sizeof(txt));
}

void bar(void)
{
    char txt[] = "Hello world";
    foo(txt);
}
```

Here you won't get 12 like before, most probably 8 (today's common size for a
pointer). Even though `txt` in `bar` is an array, the `txt` in `foo` is a
pointer.

Answer (score 2):

### "Why `p1` can't be modified?"

Roughly speaking, `p1` points to a string literal, and attempts to modify string literals cause undefined behavior in C.

More specifically, according to the [§6.4.5 6 of the C11 Standard](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.4.5p6), string literals are:

> used to initialize an array of static storage duration and length just sufficient to contain the sequence. For character string literals, the array elements have type `char`....

Concerning objects with `static` storage duration, [§5.1.2 1 states that](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.1.2p1)

> All objects with static storage duration shall be initialized (set to their initial values) before program startup. The manner and timing of such initialization are otherwise unspecified.

### "Which section of memory it's layout?"

But, the Standard does not specify any specific memory layouts that an implementation must follow.

What the Standard *does* say about the arrays of `char` which are created from string literals is that ([§6.4.5 7](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.4.5p7)):

> It is unspecified whether these arrays are distinct provided their elements have the appropriate values. **If the program attempts to modify such an array, the behavior is undefined.**

Comment: Thank you sir! i have read your link! it's good but no easy to understand!

Comment: It may take a while to get used to reading Standardese, but it is worth it if you plan to do much programming in C ;)

Comment: `C` look simple , but no easy to deep in ~

Answer (score 0):

Arrays are constant pointer, which means that an array points to a memory address and you cant change were it points. But you can change the elements in it.

While you can change where the pointer points, but it's elements are constant.

for example consider this code

```
int main(){
int a[] = {1,2,3};
int * ptr = {1,2,3};

//a[0] == *(a+0)
//a[1] == *(a+1)

a += 1; // this is wrong, because we cant change were array points
ptr += 1; // this is correct, now the pointer ptr will points to the next element which is 2

a[0] += 2 // this is correct, now a[0] will become 3
*ptr += 2 // this is wrong, because we cant change the elements of the pointer.
return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Arrays are not "constant pointers."